# Join WIP_TRANSACTIONS with WIP_RESOURCE_ACTUAL_TIMES

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I need to join the below two WIP tables, Can somebody give me the right joins to link these tables.

```
WIP_TRANSACTIONS,
WIP_RESOURCE_ACTUAL_TIMES
```

Appreciate your time and Help.